# Return If-statements

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, map-function

I am having an array of objects, which contains a `query`, `qLength`, `qStatus`, `answer`.

```
const commands = [
  {
    query: 'hello',
    qLength: 5,
    qStatus: 'reply',
    answer: 'Hello ! Have a nice day!'
  } 
]
```

I am running a `map` function to return if statements according to the array. But, it says: `Unreachable code detected !`. Here is the function:

```
commands.map((command) => {
return (
      if(msg.content.substr(0, command.qLength).toLocaleLowerCase() === command.query) {
       if(command.qStatus === 'reply') {
        msg.reply(command.answer);
       }
     }
    )  
  });
```

### Edit:

What I want, as result, is  if statements. Something like:

```
if(msg.content.substr(0,  5).toLocaleLowerCase() === "hello") { 
  if("reply" === 'reply') {
   msg.reply("Hello ! Have a nice day!");
  } 
 }

if(msg.content.substr(0,  5).toLocaleLowerCase() === "hi") { 
  if("reply" === 'reply') {
   msg.reply("Hi");
  } 
 }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated !

Comment: Is this JavaScript? You can't have if conditions in a return statement in JavaScript: https://wandbox.org/permlink/mT0oGeUPpbsAGuPq

Comment: Please don't use `.map()` for simple iteration. Use `.forEach()` or even a simple loop. With that said, what is this code supposed to *do*?

Comment: `.map()` is used to transform every item in an array. As such, it must always return something. If you're not interested in transforming every item in an array, don't use `.map()`.

Comment: from your snippets, you should use `.forEach()` instead of `.map()`

Comment: What is the expected output or action(s) ?

Comment: I have placed the expected output in the updated question. Thanks

Comment: Your explanation does not help because it does not make sense. You cannot return an `if` statement. Please state what you're trying to do, not what the wrong code is. We can see what's wrong, the question is what the correct version would be.

Comment: That I have placed in the question.    `if(msg.content.substr(0, 5).toLocaleLowerCase() === "hello") { if("reply" === 'reply') { msg.reply("Hello ! Have a nice day!"); } }`

Comment: I saw that. I'm saying it doesn't help because it doesn't explain what the purpose is. You just say you want to return an `if` statement. This is not possible. It doesn't explain what the expected output is.

Comment: Oh! Actually, there will be an array containing many objects. From each object I want to get these key's value: 'query' , 'qLength' , 'qStatus' and 'answer' . Then generate a if-condition statement for each of the object. First checking if `msg.content` is the 'query' key's value. Then, if 'qStatus' is "reply". Thats it

Comment: Please see the updated question !